# An inequality for cosine of n

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, diophantine-approximation

Can anyone provide a proof of the following inequality?
If $n$ is a positive integer, $n\geq2$, then $$\cos(n) \leq 1 - 2^{-n}.$$
This is satisfied if $n$ is not within about $2^{-n/2}$ of a multiple of $2\pi$.

This inequality is sufficient for something else I am trying to prove but I and others have been unable to prove it.

Comment: Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: For the first ten thousand $n$ it's correct. ;-)

Comment: Since the windows around increasing multiples of $n$ get smaller and smaller -- and in particular since $\sum_{n \ge 0} 2^{-n/2}$ converges -- any exceptions are likely to be small.

Answer (score 32):

It is well known that
$$|\tfrac{n}{k}-\pi|\ge \tfrac1{p(k)}$$
where $p$ is a polynomial of some very finite degree.
From this your estimate follows for all sufficiently large $n$.

The polynomial $p$ can be written explicitly; all you need to find it in the literature and check first few values of $n$ by hands...

**P.S.** According to K.Mahler 1956, one can take $p(k)=k^{42}$; i.e.; it is sufficient to check all $n\le 1000$.
So, if you trust [Martin Brandenburg](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2841/martin-brandenburg), your inequality holds for all $n$. ;-)

Comment: and of course Mahler's exponent 42 has been improved during the succeeding half-century.


Comment: This is a very clean and transparent argument, but it relies on something not-quite-elementary. Is there a really simple, elementary argument showing that, say, 
  $$ \left| \pi-\frac{n}{k} \right| > \frac1{2^k} $$ 
for all integer $k\ge k_0$? 